# Subtracting a specific date from today's date returns more than 3 days

Tags: javascript

Honestly, I don't know what's wrong. I'm using Flipclock javascript lib, and I'm trying to make a countdown to 15th January, 2015, 18:00 PM UTC. I tried many different approaches, and the one I currently have is which returns less numbers.

My code:
    var clock;

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var nDate = new Date(2015, 01, 15, 18);
    var currentDate = new Date();

    var diff = (nDate.getTime() / 1000) - (currentDate.getTime() / 1000);

    clock = $('.n-clock').FlipClock(diff, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        autoStart: true,
        countdown: true
    });
});
```

Am I doing maths wrong? If so, please, tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Is your local timezone the same as _UTC_? This code currently uses no UTC methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are numbered from zero, so the following

```
var nDate = new Date(2015, 01, 15, 18);
```

Is *February* 15th.

Once you fix this, the result is correct. In Chrome:

```
> var nDate = new Date(2015, 0, 15, 18);
> var currentDate = new Date();
> var diff = (nDate.getTime() / 1000) - (currentDate.getTime() / 1000);
> diff / 24. / 3600.
< 2.894391319445438
```

(I.e. just under three days away.)